# Got a small htaccess error in my code

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess code block that works fine well except under one particular condition:
One, I add a 'www' when there isn't one, that works. 
Two I chop off 'index.html' when that appears.

**The problem occurs, when I have NO 'www' AND "index.html' on the end.
I get the www added and then the index is chopped off and a whole URL string is added
thereby duplicating my URL and causing a 404.**

```
http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com
```

Here is my block whats wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.kisswedding\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kisswedding.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE]
```

I am sure its just a simple thing but I am too dang tired to see it so I ask you guys :)

L

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `L` flag, so that Apache will be told to stop rewriting in that rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.kisswedding\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kisswedding.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```